# Google Analytics Checkout Behaviour in single page checkout

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, analytics

I have an ecommerce website with a single-page checkout process. I'm using Google Analytics and I would like to track the progress of said process (how many users fill in their address, how many select a shipping method, etc).

I have defined all the checkout steps in Analytics, but I'm not sure if I'm sending the tracking info the right way. Right now, whenever the user finishes one of the steps, I send a new pageview:

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {...});
ga('ec:addProduct', {...});

ga('ec:setAction','checkout', { step: 1 });
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

It seems to be working, but I'm worried that sending multiple pageviews may create unrealistic statistics. Is this ok or is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: So you want to only track one page view for the checkout session? I'm not sure of the exact ga implementation, but you could always set a variable that gets assigned on the first pageView send, and then is no longer sent if the var exists moving forward...